# how to make a cross domain api call using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm trying to make an API  post call using jquery $.ajax but i'm getting the following error

```
Failed to load https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sontest.000webhostapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

any help would be appreciated.

```
$.ajax(
      'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With,content-type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": false
               },
               dataType: 'json',
               beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + spotifyDetails);
                  xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
               },
               data: "grant_type=client_credentials",
               complete: function (response) {
               },
               error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.log(errorThrown);
               }
});
```

Comment: CORS is for the SERVER, not the client. The server has to set those headers....

Comment: API likely not CORS enabled to prevent exposing credentials client side. Use a proxy to protect credentials

Comment: I still get the same exact error after deleting the headers.

Comment: @charlietfl if that's the case, how can I make an api call using ajax?

Comment: By using server side proxy. Keep your credentials there and make server to api request and point your ajax at proxy

Comment: @charlietfl can you please provide a bit more information on how to achieve that.

Comment: Not hard to research how to set up ajax proxy in whatever language server is using. It basically makes cURL request to the endpoint and prints response back to ajax request